# Service SQL Server - Fail to start

Tags: sql-server, service

I have a trouble with a service SQL EXPRESS. I found a workaround but the error comes back sometimes. It happens on a customer PC  so I want to solve the problem definitely.

My problem is :

- Sometimes, the service `SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)` fail to start

My workaround is :

- In service manager, I go on the service's properties. In `log on` tab, I remove user password and restart the service.
- The service starts properly.

I saw that it can by caused by a windows update or a user password change. How can I fix definitely this trouble ? It the third time in few months it happens, I solved it but it's not very reassuring for the customer.

Comment: Have you checked the events logs? That'll contain the reason for the failure. If you're using a Windows Account as the Service Account, you need to ensure that the password doesn't expire, otherwise the service will fail once the password is changed/expires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue sounds like the user accounts password required a change, he probably changed it but never thought to change the password the service uses.  So the next time that server reboots (and the service restarted) it failed.  This is a very common thing to happen.  The two solutions I would recommend are as follows:

- If you do not need the SQL to run under a specific account, don't have the service start as a specific user.  That is completely normal.
- If SQL must start and run as a specific user, create a user account and tell the customer this is a service account.  Make sure the account has the desired privileges.  It can be a domain or a local account and make sure the password is set to never expire.